# Replace the first word of each line with its MD5

Tags: shell-script, awk, replace, hashsum

I have file with two space separated word in each line.
I am looking for shell scrip in Unix to replace the first word of each row with its md5 hash representation.

I have tried to adjust what is mentioned in [Awk replace a column with its hash value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024464/1102512).

But, it what this solution returns for md5 hash value looks wrong.

```
md5(is) = a2a551a6458a8de22446cc76d639a9e9
```

Comment: That's because the awk answers there use `echo` and that adds a newline... Replace it with `printf %s` you'll get the right hash: `a2a551a6458a8de22446cc76d639a9e9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an inefficient and possibly suboptimal answer:

```
while read -r first rest; do
    echo "$(echo -n $first | md5sum | awk '{ print $1 }') $rest"
done <input_file
```

This will mangle the whitespace between the first word and the rest of the line, but should preserve that between subsequent words, if any.